# Is Op Amp a VCVS or VCCS

Tags: operational-amplifier

I've been asked this question a couple of times in screening tests. 
 Options are VCVS VCCS CCVS CCCS, Which one of the four options is best fit ?
And would the answer depend whether we talk about the Ideal op-amp or the non-ideal op-amp ?

Comment: The answer would depend on whether we are talking about a current feedback op-amp or a regular op amp. The real answer is that an op-amp is used in a circuit, and the circuit determines what kind of device is built. E.g. it can be a current controlled voltage source: inverting config, input resistor is 0.

Comment: What would say about a regular op-amp ?

Comment: I think @Kaz was talking about any op-amp used within a target circuit. The target circuit (with its external components and feedback points) defines whether it is VCVS, VCCS, CCCS or CCVS.

Comment: You need to define "VCVS, VCCS, etc".  These are not standard terms, or at least not commonly used.

Comment: @Kaz/Andyaka I know about various target circuit, but I've been asked this question in context to a general op-amp(no target circuit), just the op-amp. I think the answer to be VCVS, but I couldn't find it mentioned in any "book" or formal source. And Olin, VCVS- voltage controlled voltage source VCCS- voltage controlled current source.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With no other qualification, the generic term "opamp" refers to a voltage-controlled voltage source (VCVS). The input impedance is very high (essentially infinite) and the output impedance is very low (essentially zero).

Answer (score 0):

An op-amp when used in a circuit can be made to work as one of the following VCVS VCCS CCVS or CCCS.The kind of feedback that we provide to the input determines whether the circuit employing op-amp will work as a VCVS or VCCS or anything else. These lectures can help you to understand the concepts of feedback and others....
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w8Dq8blTmSA&list=PL7987F30C41A9ADCB